# Wi-Fi USB stick on custom linux system appears to be working, but the outside world cannot see it

Tags: linux, yocto, wifi

OK, I have a problem to which I cannot find a solution, or even understand what is going on.

I am working on a custom Linux system, built using yocto Linux, and I have installed a driver in our kernel for the RTL8192cu chipset. The install worked, and using iwconfig I have started the driver etc. The chipset is from an ASUS USB-N10 Nano USB stick. From the embedded system, it appears that the card/stick/chipset is functioning, the blue light blinks etc, but when I scan the area using my smartphone as a scanner (using both ScanFi  and Wifi analyzer) I don't see any trace of the Wi-Fi stick, nothing at all.

Here is the output from  iwconfig:

```
wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I cannot use `iwconfig` to set any of the signal values etc, I always get the result `operation not permitted`.

This is what I get back when I use `ifconfig`:

```
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:31:BF:56:DD:7E  
          inet addr:192.168.1.99  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:87 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

When I use `iwlist txpower` i get the following:

```
wlan1     unknown transmit-power information.
```

I am not an expert on this system by any means, nor with yocto Linux etc. It's possible that I'm missing a key program somewhere, but it does appear to me that I have brought up the card correctly, why else would it show using the above commands and why would the LED be blinking.

Comment: Are you trying to setup the linux system as a WiFi access point (to which other systems would connect), or to connect the new system to your existing WiFi network?

Comment: the first, we are trying to set the custom Linux system up so that other systems connect to the custom Linux system, most likely using an app on android ( which of course doesn't exist yet).

Comment: i will be completely honest. for all i know i have gone as far as i can at this point. i have never built this kind of system before, but it seems to me that at the very least my WLAN detection apps should see some kind of device in the area, nothing appears anywhere.

Comment: You need an app to setup/manage the WiFi connection (what role it should perform; on what frequencies, etc...)  Google "hostapd" and see if that helps.

Comment: thank you ill try that first thing tomorrow, gettin late here (im in Bavaria)